# Is Kris Gethin's 12 week body transformation a good program for a novice?

Tags: workout-routines, training

About me:
 Height:- 179cms
 Weight:- 71kg

I am a 20 years old guy with a maximum of 2 months of gym experience. Lately I have been thinking of following a routine for body transformation and muscle building, but am having trouble finding some good routines online. There a lot of options and most of them different from each other which is making me confused over which to follow.

I was advised by my friend to follow Kris Gethin's 12 week body transformation routine. Is it good if not than can anyone point me to a right routine for a beginner like me.

Comment: As a beginner you want a simple program with a high frequency. Kris Gethin's program is neither (many different exercises, high split -> low frequency). Starting Strength is never a bad idea, but if you could elaborate on your goals there're also other programs that might fit you more.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla My aim is mainly muscle building and would like to avoid supplements if it can be avoided.

Comment: Then I can indeed recommend [Starting Strength](http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=998224), as it focuses mainly on strength and doesn't really call for any supplements. You won't build a six-pack with that program, but you _will_ build a solid strength base to work from.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla I was following a routine similar to Starting Strength for a month , thats when I thought of moving to something which will result in body building and body transformation. Can you suggest.

Comment: I'm more of a  first-bulk-then-cut person. If you want transformation/recomposition I don't think I'm the right person to recommend anything, as I've never done that before.